# Publishing modules to pip and PyPi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have created a module using **python**. I want to publish it to **pip and PyPi** so that others can download and use it easily. How do I do it?

Comment: write `setup.py` first, then run `python setup.py sdist`, then upload `dist/your_module.tar.gz` to remote server.

Comment: This cannot be explained in a single answer or comment. Try this article. https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be easily found on the Internet. I just referenced [this site](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56) to answer you. You can follow the steps below:

1. create an account on [`PyPi`](https://pypi.org/account/register/).
2. Create a `README.md` file as an instruction for users (Highly recommended).
3. Create a `setup.cfg` file, and write the following content:

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
```

4. Create a `LICENSE` file by referencing [this website](https://opensource.org/licenses/).
5. As @Yang HG mentioned, write a `setup.py` file, followed by running `python setup.py sdist`.
6. Upload your distribution by using `twine`. First, you need to `pip install twine`, then run `twine upload dist/*`.

Finally, your distribution can be viewed on `https://pypi.org/project/YOURPACKAGENAME/`

Answer (score 8):

This is well documented in [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

### Creating README.md

Create a file named `README.md` and edit it as you like (in Markdown).

### Creating `setup.py`

`setup.py` is the build script for `setuptools`. It tells `setuptools` about your package (such as the name and version) as well as which code files to include.

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg-your-username",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="YOUR NAME",
    author_email="YOUR EMAIL",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

### Creating a LICENSE

Create a file named `LICENSE` and choose your content from [here](https://choosealicense.com/).

### Generating distribution archives

The next step is to generate distribution packages for the package. These are archives that are uploaded to the Package Index and can be installed by pip.
We first need to make sure we have `wheel` and `setuptools` installed:

```py
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

Now we need to run the following command from the same directory `setup.py` is located:

```py
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

### Uploading the distribution archives

It is recommended to upload to [TestPyPi](https://test.pypi.org/) before the actual PyPi - although I will not cover this part.
The following steps show how to upload your package to PyPi:

1. Install `twine`:

```py
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade twine
```

2. Register to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).
3. Run `twine` to upload `dist` packages to PyPi:

```py
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your package using this tool i made, find source code: https://gist.github.com/lamoboos223/e1b8e3638e3b5eddd01ae0bf2d1c8d73

It’s an interactive tool that will generate a `setup.py` file. Then it will ask you which env of pypi you would like to publish your package to.