# How to build and install a Python package locally without uploading to PyPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-install

I created a small [Python project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/fdroid-build-checker) using a [project template](https://github.com/sourcery-ai/python-best-practices-cookiecutter). Now I would like to configure the project to be **locally** installable.

When I run the command:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install fdroid_build_checker
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fdroid_build_checker (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for fdroid_build_checker

A future step would be to configure the project to be published as a small command line tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring so that pip install can work from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github)

Comment: Note that you have not published your project on PyPi, so your code cannot find matching distribution on PyPI. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129825/publishing-modules-to-pip-and-pypi or google how to do it

Answer (score 4):

Your command is searching for the package in PyPi, which won't work because you haven't published the package there.

To install a local package, you should be able to just run `pip install path_containing_fdroid_build_checker/froid_buildchecker`

You'll have to make sure that your package contains a `setup.py` file (1) in order for `pip` to build a wheel and install it successfully.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537134/2741222

1 - https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py